# How to reinitialize a method within python class with updated object value

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I want to have a class and be able to change an object value and have it flow through to methods and objects created in the class.  In the below example I am trying have the new value `3` flow through but I keep getting the original value `2`.  Am I doing it wrong?

```
class fun:
  g=2
  def a(c=g):
    return c
  z=g

fun.g = 3
fun.a()
fun.z
```

I have searched for `__init__` functions but I don't see how they can help here.  I tried created a new class making is the same as the `fun` class.  That didn't work either.

Comment: You're facing a couple different issues here, but It sounds like you're seeking `getters` and `setters`. In python the `@property` decorator is used for this purpose.

Comment: Changing the default argument value of an existing function  is possible, though not really recommended.

Comment: Be sure to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info and reading material, super helpful.  I have to approach in totally different way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as otheres mentioned, just want to point out that  `def a(c=g):` the `g` has been replaced with 2 during class creation.

so after

```py
fun.g = 3

print(fun.__dict__)
```

```
mappingproxy({'__module__': '__main__',
              'g': 3,
              'a': <function __main__.fun.a(c=2)>,
              'z': 2,
              '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'fun' objects>,
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'fun' objects>,
              '__doc__': None})
```

As you can see `'a': <function __main__.fun.a(c=2)>,`

Answer (score 2):

In python, methods and functions have their default values calculated and stored when the method or function is declared.

You can defer that calculation by doing it inside the method at runtime:

```py
class fun:
  g=2
  def a(c=None):  # None is used here as a sentinal value
    if c is None:
        c=fun.g
    return c
  z=g
```

Comment: This doesn't update the value of `fun.z`, though. I think the idea was to be able to update  several things depending on the value of `fun.g` with only one change.

Comment: `z = property(lambda self: self.g)`, perhaps.

Comment: Well, just omit `z`. Use `g` instead!

Comment: @chepner you are right, really just shorthand sample for how to make several updates with one change...unfortunately I can't seem to find a way to do this in a way that makes the code simple/readable.  Essentially tons of methods/objects within a class need to inherit this value which will change from use to use

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that parameters of a function is evaluated at **compile time** not runtime! Because in compile time the value of `g` is 2 and in your function you return that value, it's always going to be 2.

As a point, you call `a()` function on the class itself, so it's first parameter is not going to be filled with a reference to an instance. Story changes when you try to call it from instance of that class.

For demonstration take a look at this :

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

class C:
    def fn(self, date=datetime.now()):
        return date

obj = C()
print(obj.fn())
sleep(2)
print(obj.fn())
```

They both have same value.

The solution is to put `g` equal to None for default value and then inside the function check whether that value is passed or not:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

class C:
    def fn(self, date=None):
        if date:
            return date
        return datetime.now()

obj = C()
print(obj.fn())
sleep(2)
print(obj.fn())
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure quite what you mean by reinitialize, `__init__` occurs only on creation. If you create a new `fun` object it will be initialized in the same way with the same value.

```
$ cat fun.py

class fun(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.g = 2

    def a(self, c=None):
        if c is None:
            c = self.g
        return c


first = fun()
second = fun()

first.g = 3

print(first.g)
print(first.a())
print(second.g)
print(second.a())
```

```
$ python3 fun.py
3
3
2
2
```